# How do I customize the doctrine default CRUD generator views

Tags: symfony, doctrine

How do I override the layout so my next `doctrine:generate:crud` will generate items inside an `ul` list element instead of the `table` tag?

PS: `table` to `ul` is only an simple example; I'd like to do more cutomizations.

Comment: What version of Symfony are you on? Have you tried https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle ?

Comment: Symfony 3.4 and/or 4.1